# Why its not following template from formatter

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Here is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
                log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                fileName="F:\MyLogFile.log" footer="" header="" rollInterval="Hour"
                traceOutputOptions="None" formatter="Text Formatter" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                template="{timestamp} {severity} {message} "
                name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

when I use the code below

```
 Logger.Write("hello world", "", 0, 0, TraceEventType.Information);
```

I get following in the log file

> 3/4/2011 7:40:26 PM Error There is no explicit mapping for the categories ''. The log entry was:
>   Timestamp: 3/4/2011 7:40:26 PM
>   Message: Hello World
>   Category:
>   Priority: 0
>   EventId: 0
>   Severity: Information
>   Title:
>   Machine: MyPC
>   App Domain: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe
>   ProcessId: 8912
>   Process Name: C:\ConsoleApplication\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe
>   Thread Name:
>   Win32 ThreadId:5496
>   Extended Properties:

What am I doing wrong that make it not respecting the template="{timestamp} {severity} {message} " that I have defined in formatter.

Comment: What logger do you use? and show all the config file

Comment: Enterpriese library Logging Block. What you see missing in config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your category with the name "General" but when you log you are using the category "".

```
Logger.Write("hello world", "", 0, 0, TraceEventType.Information);
```

So your LogEntry is not being processed by your "General" category but instead by the `specialSource` `notProcessed`.  That's what the message "There is no explicit mapping for the categories" is trying to tell you.

To use your category pass the name in to the `Write` method:

```
Logger.Write("hello world", "General", 0, 0, TraceEventType.Information);
```

or don't specify a category since "General" is defined as the defaultCategory.

Comment: Thanks, however now I am getting "Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key "" " error. Not sure if this may be cuased by the fact that enterprise library logging block is configured in dll. I have posted a separate question on it though.